# servlets connectivity & running on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How can I use this path: `"file:///E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.10/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/match.html"` ? Is this correct?

This is my html file:

```
<html>
    <form method=post action="../classes/match1">
    <body bgcolor="powderblue">
        <center><h1>MATCH</h1>
        <hr/>

        MATCH NO         <input type="text" name="op1"/><br/><pre>
        DATE             <input type="text" name="op2"/><br/><pre>
        CITY            <input type="text" name="op3"/><br/><pre>
        TEAM1            <input type="text" name="op4"/><br/><pre>
        TEAM2            <input type="text" name="op5"/><br/><pre>
        STADIUM          <input type="text" name="op6"/><br/><pre>
        WINNER           <input type="text" name="op7"/><br/><pre>
        MAN OF THE MATCH <input type="text" name="op8"/><br/><pre>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>&nbsp
        <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

My servlet code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Date.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class match1 extends HttpServlet {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException {
        try {
            PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
            con=null;
            pst=null;
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:gan","scott","tiger");
            int count=0;
            String op1=req.getParameter("op1");
            String op2=req.getParameter("op2");
            String op3=req.getParameter("op3");
            String op4=req.getParameter("op4");
            String op5=req.getParameter("op5");
            String op6=req.getParameter("op6");
            String op7=req.getParameter("op7");
            String op8=req.getParameter("op8");
            pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into matchdetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,op1);
            pst.setString(2,op2);
            pst.setString(3,op3);
            pst.setString(4,op4);
            pst.setString(5,op5);
            pst.setString(6,op6);
            pst.setString(7,op7);
            pst.setString(8,op8);
            out.println("<html><center><body>matched</body></center></html>");
            int count1=pst.executeUpdate();
            if(count1==0) {
                out.println("<html><center><body>ENTER ALL FIELD VALUES</body></center></html>");
            } else {
                out.println("<html><center><body>INSERTION SUCCESFUL</body></center></html>");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con!=null) con.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use this path: "file:///E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.10/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/match.html" ? Is this correct?

You mean, how to access it by a webbrowser? No, that path is not correct. Tomcat listens on HTTP requests only. When started properly, it by default listens on http://localhost:8080. All webapps get their own context name which defaults to the webapp folder name. So your webapp is accessible by http://localhost:8080/examples. However, files in `/WEB-INF` folder are not directly accessible. You need to move the `match.html` one level up, in the `/examples` folder. Then you'll be able to access it by http://localhost:8080/examples/match.html.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, declaring connection and statement as instance variable of the servlet is a poor practice. This is not threadsafe. You need to declare them inside the method block, right before the `try` statement. Your HTML has also some syntax errors. Use http://validator.w3.org to learn about them. Finally, emitting raw HTML in servlets is also a poor practice, there you normally use JSPs for. But maybe you're currently just learning. Just to let you know :) Already using preparedstatements and closing the connection in finally is very good for a starter.

As to learning JSP/Servlets, I'd suggest to read our info/wiki pages as well.

- [JSP info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

- First, your html need to be a little
  cleaner (see below).
- Second, if you
  want `match.html`, don't use `match1`
  in the form action.
- Third, put the
  `match.html` file under the `war`
  folder, not `web-inf`.
- Fourth, you
  will need to set up the `web.xml`
  configuration file.

I did not even look yet at the servlet class, but I would suggest first to test some `System.out.println()` output to make sure it is even executed.

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="powderblue">
        <center>
            <h1>MATCH</h1>
            <form method="post" action="/match.html">
                <pre>MATCH NO         <input type="text" name="op1"/></pre>
                <pre>DATE             <input type="text" name="op2"/></pre>
                <pre>CITY             <input type="text" name="op3"/></pre>
                <pre>TEAM1            <input type="text" name="op4"/></pre>
                <pre>TEAM2            <input type="text" name="op5"/></pre>
                <pre>STADIUM          <input type="text" name="op6"/></pre>
                <pre>WINNER           <input type="text" name="op7"/></pre>
                <pre>MAN OF THE MATCH <input type="text" name="op8"/></pre>
                <pre><input type="submit" value="submit"/></pre>
                <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```